# Abrupt cmd_vel change from + to - causes rattle in robot

Tags: ros-humble

I am using the Carter robot and want to manipulate it back and forth using cmd_vel topic.

While testing with multiple commands, when I publish the joint twist message such as x: 0.5 and then x: -0.5, the robot rattles and then goes backward.

I want to add some deceleration functions and want to know where I can find some hints to implement them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems more like a robot motor controller gain tuning issue than a cmd_vel one, look in the control loop on your microcontroller/motor controller.

At least on the standard `Twist` messages sent alongside `cmd_vel`, there aren't any fields for acceleration.